# Client Server Runtime Process and Desktop Window Manager consumes my GPU

Tags: gpu, process, task-manager, high-cpu-usage

Here is it

[image]

Why and how to retake my GPU bak for me? :)

---

[image]

Comment: Just a guess... what happens if you close Chrome? What other programs are running? Have you rebooted?

Answer (score 1):

The "Client Server Runtime Process" (or `csrss.exe`) is an essential
Windows component and does not use heavily the GPU.
However, many bitcoin mining viruses love to disguise themselves as
this process, and they do use the GPU.

I suggest using
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
to verify that the running process is indeed `C:\Windows\System32\csrss.exe`.

If that truly the case and this is the legitimate process, then something is wrong
with Windows.
Start with running the commands
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
and the DISM command in the article.
If this doesn't help, do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If the process is not legitimate, run deep antivirus scans using at least
Windows Defender and
[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).
For more advice see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: I found "verify" button in `procexp` and it showed "verified" against publisher. Although at the moment of test, `csrss` was not consuming `GPU` while `dwm` was. Verifying of it also shown ok.

Comment: Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe) renders all those pretty effects in Windows and cannot be turned off. It should use fairly minimal resources, except perhaps for some intense graphical applications (although I have never encountered such).